# Verifying keycloak token on multiple microservices

Tags: node.js, jwt, keycloak, keycloak-services

I have a web app that does the login to keycloak server and gets the JWT token from keycloak server.

The it fires and api and for the completion of the request it goes to multiple microservices. I want to verify the keycloak JWT token  on these microservices without contacting to keycloak server every time.

These microservices are written in nodejs

Answer (score 0):

If you use the nodejs Keycloak Adapter ( https://www.npmjs.com/package/keycloak-connect ) , your JWT will be verified. The first time the adapter contacts the keycloak server but it won't contact it at each requests after that.